# Can I add more than two arguments to get_context_data()?

Tags: django, get, request, typeerror, django-context

I get this error

```
TypeError at /debate/1/
get_context_data() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Right now it is defined as:

```
 def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
```

And I want it to be:

```
 def get_context_data(self, request, **kwargs):
```

so I can do inside:

```
sort_by = request.GET.get('sort', '-rating_score')
```

Is this a good idea, and how to do it?

Comment: Do you using generic classes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Request object is available as member of a Class Based View object and can be accessed by `self.request`. If, for some reason, you do pass it in `**kwargs` use `kwargs.get("request")` since it's a plain dict.